# update query is not working with my code

Tags: php

I am trying to update the record in my database but after submiting form it does not go back to the page committee.php and records does not get updated. Is there any problem with my query?

```
    <?php
    include_once('connection.php');




    if(isset($_GET['details_id']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['details_id'];
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {


            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $pageno = $_POST['page'];
            $author = $_POST['author'];
            //$authorimg = $_POST['image'];

            $article_status = $_POST['articlestatus'];
            $sketch_status = $_POST['sketchstatus'];
            $final_approval_person = $_POST['finalperson'];
            $final_approval_date = $_POST['finaldate'];
            $status = $_POST['status'];

                        $query = "update details set title='$title', page_no='$pageno', author='$author', article_status='$article_status', sketch_status='$sketch_status', final_approve_person='$final_approval_person', final_approve_date='$final_approval_date', status='$status', where id=$id";

        $res = mysqli_query($DBCONNECT,$query);      


        if($res)
        {
            header('location:committee.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo mysql_error();
        }


        }

    }


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin-left:30%;">

<div class="form-style-2">
<div class="form-style-2-heading">Provide Following Information</div>
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="field1"><span>Title <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="title" value="" /></label>

<label for="field1"><span>Page No. </span><input type="number" class="input-field" name="page"
   min="0" max="100" step="10" value="30"></label>

<label for="field2"><span>Author <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="author" value="" /></label>

<label for="field1"><span>Author Image <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="file" class="input-field" name="image" value="" /></label>

<label for="field4"><span>Article Status</span><select name="articlestatus" class="select-field">
<option value="notrecieved">Not Recieved</option>
<option value="recieved">Recieved</option>
</select></label>

<label for="field4"><span>Sketch Status</span><select name="sketchstatus" class="select-field">
<option value="notapproved">Not Approved</option>
<option value="approved">Approved</option>
</select></label>

<label for="field2"><span>Final Approval Person <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="finalperson" value="" /></label>

<label for="field2"><span>Final Approval Date <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="date" class="input-field" name="finaldate" value="" /></label>

<label for="field2"><span>Status <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="status" value="" /></label>





<!--<label for="field4"><span>Regarding</span><select name="field4" class="select-field">
<option value="General Question">General</option>
<option value="Advertise">Advertisement</option>
<option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
</select></label>
<label for="field5"><span>Message <span class="required">*</span></span><textarea name="field5" class="textarea-field"></textarea></label>
-->
<label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></label>
</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` <-- place that at the top of your file, you should see your error, basic debugging is as much part of coding as writing it is.

Comment: after submitting is shows only blank form

Comment: see this line for edit button                                                                      <td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm Updation');\" href='edit.php?details_id=".$details_id."'>Edit&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></td>

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. Use this

```
$query = "update details set title='$title', page_no='$pageno', 
    author='$author', article_status='$article_status', 
    sketch_status='$sketch_status', final_approve_person='$final_approval_person', 
    final_approve_date='$final_approval_date', status='$status' where id=$id";
```

No need comma here `status='$status', where id=$id`

Also add single quote for $id in the where clause.

Comment: Add single quote for $id in the where clause

Comment: am i putting this correct on my edit button from committee.php page?

Comment: <td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm Updation');\" href='edit.php?details_id=".$details_id."'>Edit&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></td>

Comment: `href='edit.php?details_id=<?php echo $details_id; ?>'>` better show the full code!